# Output not matching

Tags: c, pointers

The following code gives output as `AVA` , but I am not being able to understand why? In my opinion the output should be `++`, because as C = B it will point to the strings stored at `A+2 , A+1 , A+3 , A` , and after `++C` it will start pointing from `A+1`, which is C++. But it points to `JAVA`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   char * A[] = {"C", "C++", "JAVA", "PHP"};
   char **B[] = {A+2, A+1, A+3, A}, ***C;
   C = B;
   ++C;
   printf("%s", *(*C+1)+1);
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break it down...  You have `*(*C+1)+1`.  Let's find the value of C for starters and work through it:

1. `C = B;`

   B's array type is elided to a `char***` and C now points at the first element of B
2. `++C;`

   C is incremented by 1, and now points at the second element of B
3. Evaluation of `(*C+1)`:

   `*C` is equivalent to `B[1]` and gives you the pointer `A+1`.  You add 1 to it, so `(*C+1)` is equivalent to `A+2`.
4. Evaluation of `*(*C+1)+1`:

   From the explanation above, this is now equivalent to `*(A+2) + 1`, which is `A[2] + 1`.  That points at the string "AVA".

Finally, a note on style: *don't ever write code like this!*